# Multivariable Calculus Books

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate student currently taking a course in Multivariable Calculus. Long story short, I took a hiatus from doing any sort of serious mathematics for a couple of years, and now that I am back I am finding it difficult to pick up where I left off.

The "textbook" that we are using is more of a collection of notes, lacking any sort of practice problems, other than in-text, usually trivial proofs, and I find that the practice problems posted (usually about 5-10 per week) are insufficient practice for me.

I am posting to see if any of you have suggestions for a good multivariable calculus textbook that has clear and detailed explanations, and lots of practice problems.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stewart Multivariable Calculus is one of my favourite  books

Comment: I used to recommend "How to Ace the REST of Calculus."  Adams, et al.   It's a sequel to "How to Ace Calculus".  But while I didn't like the first book, the second was stable and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try

- A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis by Ghorpade, Sudhir R., Limaye, Balmohan V. [[Springer link]](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441916204)
- Calculus. Vol 2 ., Multi Variable Calculus and Linear
  Algebra, with Applications to
  Differential Equations and Probability by Tom M Apostol ([Pdf](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Maths/Calculus/Tom%20Apostol%20-%20Calculus%20Vol.2%20-%20Multi-Variable%20Calculus%20and%20Linear%20Algebra%20with%20Applications.pdf) !)

Answer (score 1):

See [Calculus with Analytic Geometry](https://www.amazon.com.br/Calculus-Analytic-Geometry-George-Simmons/dp/0070576424) by George Finlay Simmons.  A student friendly book with many relevant exercises.